# Get the value of a InterpolatedStringExpressionSyntax

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

Using Roslyn, I'm to get the constant value of the following string parameter in this method call:

```
inst.someMethod($"{Constants.SomeValue}");
```

```
static class Constants
{
    public static readonly string SomeValue= "some value";
}
```

I got an instance of `InterpolatedStringExpressionSyntax` type for the `$"{Constants.SomeValue}"` parameter.

Next, I need to get its value (which is the `"Some value"` string), and I tried to call `semanticModel.GetConstantValue(expr);` but it returns null

How can I get that value?

Comment: "Next, I need to get its value" - that would be something evaluated at execution time. I wouldn't expect Roslyn to be able to do that. I'd expect Roslyn to be able to give you the format string of `{0}` and the argument expression of `Constants.SomeValue`, but that's not the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

1) `SemanticModel.GetConstantValue` works only for compile time constant members, so you cannot use it to get a value of readonly field.

2) If you want to get a value of readonly field you actually need to analyze field initializer and constructors in the common cases to determine where and how this field was created and so on.
But in you simple example above, when you have a `static class` and static `readonly field` with initializer you can make something looks ike this:

```cs
InterpolatedStringExpressionSyntax interpolatedExpression = // you received it before
// as you know that your member is the first contet of InterpolatedStringExpressionSyntax 
var symbolInfo = semanticModel.GetSymbolInfo(((interpolatedExpression).Contents[0] as InterpolationSyntax).Expression);
if (!(symbolInfo.Symbol is null))
{
    // assume that exists only a one declaration
    var fieldDeclaration = symbolInfo.Symbol.DeclaringSyntaxReferences[0].GetSyntax() as VariableDeclaratorSyntax;
    if (!(fieldDeclaration is null))
    {
        // retrieves text from `SomeValue = "some value"`
        var text = (fieldDeclaration.Initializer.Value as LiteralExpressionSyntax)?.Token.Text;
    }
}
```